# Is amount of heat transferred depended upon the kind of materials or just the diffrence in temperature of two bodies?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, thermal-conductivity

I was studying calorimeter and this question came to my mind that whether heat released from chemical reaction dependent only upon temperature or also on the kind of material used as "heat absorber or releaser".

To put it in other way, if we have two isolated systems consisting of two objects, say $(A\ ,\ B)$ and $(A \ ,\ C)$, where $B$ and $C$ are different substance but have same temperature and $A$ has higher temperature from the both, then will the the heat transferred from $A$ to $B$ same as heat transferred from $A$ to $C$?

For example if a reaction is carried out in calorimeter with water, as the "*heat absorbent*", having certain temperature, then will the same heat released by the reaction if  we used anything other than water, having the same temperature as water had?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Le Chatelier’s principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier's_principle)?

Comment: @Chemomechanics No, I don't know it.

Comment: The surrounding temperature generally affects how far a reaction proceeds (and the resulting heat transfer), as described in the link.

Comment: @Chemomechanics yes but in this case we have just replaced water with other material having same temprature as water.

Comment: If the new material has a different [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity), then it will heat up differently than water and thus change the nature of reaction. Perhaps this is the parameter you're interested in?

Comment: @Chemomechanics you're right in that the new material will heat up differently, in the sense that the final temparture of this material after the rxn will be diffrent from that of water. But I am asking whether heat released from the rxn dependent upon the material surrounding "the bomb"(bomb calorimeter) or just the temprature of the sorrounding material? Surely the final temprature of materials surrounding will be diffrent from each other but did they receive same amount of heat?

Comment: Any difference in the reaction temperature (or pressure, for example) will typically alter the reaction kinetics, including the heat output. That heat output also tends to change the surrounding temperature. It's a coupled problem that might require an iterative solution: calculate the temperature of the alternate material, then check whether this temperature changed the reaction kinetics and evolved heat, recalculate the temperature change, and continue until convergence. Try doing this for your example and adding the results to your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a property called **thermal heat capacity** that determines how much heat it takes per gram to increase an object’s temperature by one degree $C$. (in SI)

Also, in practice before steady state, there is a thermal gradient inside each object which affects its surface temperature, and that surface temperature affects how heat will transfer to/from it. The surface temperature is affected by the property **thermal conductivity** because that determines how well heat will flow away from the surface into the body of the object. If it conducts heat well then even as you heat it up, the surface will stay cool because the heat is being transmitted into the mass of the object well. The cooler surface will make more heat from the hot object come in (due to the bigger temperature difference between the two surfaces).

The first property of the material applies even in theory and steady state. The second applies in practice (reality) before reaching steady state.

So yes, it depends on material(s) involved.